# How can i add additional field to each object in array node using jackson java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jsonnode

i have list of masters that have two fields that are name and rating and after  serialization to array node i need to add one more field to each object
for example i have json

```
[{"masterName":"Bruce","rating":30},{"masterName":"Tom","rating":25}]
```

and i have list of servisec in json format that look like that

```
[{"masterName":"Bruce","services":["hair coloring","massage"]},{"masterName":"Tom","services":["hair coloring","haircut"]}]
```

i need it to looks something like that

```
[{"masterName":"Bruce","rating":30,"services":"hair coloring,massage"},{"masterName":"Tom","rating":25,"services":"hair coloring, haircut"}]
```

How can do it by using jackson?

Comment: Jackson is just for handling json, if you're aggregating data, deserialize everything into java objects, process your data and serialize it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way. Since you want to use Jackson.

First of all, I would extend the `Master` class by adding the `services` (which seems to be an array with `Strings`).

So the class would look something like this:

```java
    public class Master
    {
        private String masterName;
        private int rating;
        private List<String> services = new ArrayList<>(); // THE NEW PART
        
        // Whatever you have else in your class
    }
```

Then you could get your JSON array, I am supposing that it comes as a `String` for simplicity. Serialize this array in an array with `Master` objects and then you can add the services as said above.

e.g.

```java
    String yourJsonString = "[{\"masterName\":\"Bruce\",\"rating\":30},{\"masterName\":\"Tom\",\"rating\":25}]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    List<Master> theListOfMasters = new ArrayList<>();

    // Read them and put them in an Array
    Master[] mastersPlainArr = mapper.readValue(yourJsonString, Master[].class);

    theListOfMasters = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(mastersPlainArr));

    // then you can get your masters and edit them..

    theListOfMasters.get(0).getServices.add("A NEW SERVICE...");

    // And so on...

    // Then you can turn them in a JSON array again:

    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(theListOfMasters);
```